# Two subplots coming out too long (length)

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm attempting to plot two bar charts using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`. I've created subplots within a function, but when I output the subplots they are too long in height and not long enough in width.

Here's the function that I wrote:

```
def corr_bar(data1, data2, method='pearson'):

    # Basic configuration.
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 7))
    ax1, ax2 = axes
    corr_matrix1 = data1.corr(method=method)
    corr_matrix2 = data2.corr(method=method)
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
    major_ticks = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)
    minor_ticks = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.05)

    # Values for plotting.
    x1 = corr_matrix1['price'].sort_values(ascending=False).index
    x2 = corr_matrix2['price'].sort_values(ascending=False).index
    values1 = corr_matrix1['price'].sort_values(ascending=False).values
    values2 = corr_matrix2['price'].sort_values(ascending=False).values

    im1 = ax1.bar(x1, values1, color=cmap(values1))
    im2 = ax2.bar(x2, values2, color=cmap(values2))

    # Formatting for plot 1.
    ax1.set_yticks(major_ticks)
    ax1.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
    plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor')
    ax1.grid(which='both')
    ax1.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.4)
    ax1.grid(which='major', alpha=0.7)
    ax1.xaxis.grid(False)

    # Formatting for plot 2.
    ax2.set_yticks(major_ticks)
    ax2.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
    plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor')
    ax2.grid(which='both')
    ax2.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.4)
    ax2.grid(which='major', alpha=0.7)
    ax2.xaxis.grid(False)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

This function (when run with two Pandas DataFrames) outputs an image like the following:

[image]

I purposely captured the blank right side of the image as well in an attempt to better depict my predicament. What I want is for the bar charts to be appropriately sized in height and width as to take up the entire space, rather than be elongated and pushed to the left.

I've tried to use the `ax.set(aspect='equal')` method but it "scrunches up" the bar chart. Would anybody happen to know what I could do to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't replicate your error. Also provide a minimum and verifiable [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You set the figure to be square yourself (via `figsize=(7, 7)`). To make it twice as wide use e.g. `figsize=(14, 7)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `figsize=(7,7)` you are setting the size of the entire figure and not the subplots. So your entire figure must be a square in this case. You should change it to `figsize=(14,7)` or use a number larger than 14 to get a little bit of extra space.